# Laravel Public Folder Path Issue - Some assets not loading

Tags: apache, laravel, nginx

From what I can tell, I've successfully installed Laravel. I've restored and existing site. All blades load and everything works properly.

But the issue is that I get 404 on a few assets from the public folder. All images, css, and some JS, but not all. The assets are in fact there...

I'm running apache, but the error is 404 Not Found - nginx

Is it that nginx and apache are running side by side and I need to create a nginx conf for the domain as well as apache conf? if this is the case, is there anyway to use apache exclusively?

Comment: Why do you have both Apache and nginx?

Comment: That's really part of the question. Why am I getting the nginx error if I'm running apache. nginx is not the web server.

Comment: First decide if you want to use apache or nginx. Once decided stop one and check for errors on that...

Comment: @Lee Stopping Stopping nginx shuts down all domains on the server even though they are running on Apache. Shutting down Apache does the same thing -- no domains are accessible

Comment: Just checked in plesk. Nginx was running as a reverse proxy server. So thankfully Apache has now taken over everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx was running as a reverse server proxy. Shutdown through Plesk. Apache took over and all assets rendered.